# WordPress CSS Not loading

Tags: css, wordpress, amazon-web-services, docker

trying to install a fresh WordPress Install using Docker Compose. I'm using AWS EC2 with a ELB
Everything looks fine on logs but once I access to my site I got no css loaded, see the screen :
[no css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVOeN.png)

And the network error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxhgT.png)

Here is my docker-compose :

```
version: "3"
services:
 wordpress:
  image: conetix/wordpress-with-wp-cli
  ports: 
    - 80:80
  restart: always
  environment:
    - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=namehostwp
    - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=nameuserwp
    - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=passworddbwp
    - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=namedbwp
  volumes: 
    - ./wp_data:/var/www/html
```

This image is wordpress and wp cli.
Then I run :
`docker exec <container id> wp core install --path="/var/www/html" --url="http://nomdomaine" title="Example" --admin_user=supervisor --admin_password=strongpassword --admin_email=info@example.com`
Install went well, and in wp-config I got the good dbhost, dbuser, dbpw and dbname

All files seems ok
[plugins ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIajU.png)

I dont know what to do.. thx for any help / tips

EDIT : stylesheet url : [stylesheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8Jlj.png)

Comment: Please show the network tab error

Comment: It says : ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: When you view the html source what is the stylesheet url? does  that link work? does the file exist?
Have you cleared any cache - any browser or server side cache?

Comment: Added stylesheet url

Comment: View source of the page and click on the stylesheet links, see if it loads the CSS or no, If you can't access it then it is not correct path or not correct access permission or CORS Problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you haven't properly configured your domain name and as result the css file can not be loaded.  That's what your error `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` means